# How can I derive hierarchical draw ordering for entities in an entity system?

Tags: rendering, entity

How do you implement hierarchical render order in an entity system?

For example: two player entities each carry a gun entity. If you set the player entities to zindex = 0 and the gun entities to zindex = 1, then player 1 might render behind player 2 but his gun will render in front of player two.

I'm migrating a game from a scene-graph system where the order is self-evident from the parent/child relationship. The only way I can see of achieving the above is to simulate that parent/child relationship by giving every entity its own reserved range of z-indexes like so.
player1 z=0
player1-gun z=1
...
player2 z=5
player2-gun z=6

This would require some kind of auto assignment system. Is this how it's done or is there some pattern I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one way that "it's done," really; it sounds like you may be coupling you renderer and your entity system too tightly together (generally they don't really need to know about eachother). However, it seems like a straightforward solution to your problem is to introduce hierarchy to the appropriate components.

Presumably the gun entity has either a transform component or a visualization component with transform information. Or perhaps tranformation is considered important enough to be a first-class property of an entity in your system.

In any case, add the notion of a parent reference to whichever aspect of your system has the transformation information. They you can recover the Z order information you need from that hierarchical structure, just like you would in a graph system:

Order your top level components by whatever predicate you consider appropriate to break Z-order ties (such as by their screen height). Assign the first component the next available Z index, and then assign successive Z indices to its children before moving on to the next top-level component.

This will not solve every possible problem, but it will put you back into the same problem space as a graph-based solution.

Comment: Ah yes I get you. I've been looking at the Unity Transform component but it hadn't occurred to me to use it as the sorting order. I can't visualise exactly how I'm going to work it yet but it gives me a line of study. 
Thanks Josh.